# How to sort html table month name with year

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, tablesorter

Is there a way to sort a table with the following format of date string(month name and year) in JavaScript? I tried to use the bootstrap table plugin, but I think it only sort it as string,

```
<table data-toggle="table" >
<thead>
    <tr><th>name</th><th data-sortable="true" >date</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>row1</td><td>Dec 2004</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row2</td><td>Jan 2010</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row3</td><td>Feb 2011</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row4</td><td>Feb 2010</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: add the code that you tried already

Comment: basically those are all the code, just need to include the bootstrap JS and CSS, and it will be able to sort, but just not sort correctly with those date

Comment: so add them. build a complete **working** example that shows (not code, real view) what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/), I used it often and it works well.
There is also an option to sort dates exactly like you want it, check it out [here](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#dates)

## EDITED

If you really want to keep the dates in that format with text for the month instead of digits, you'll have to go with custom value for the sorting.

[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1NB4anOJy76BkLG4vO9r?p=preview) is an example using your code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="sortable">
      <thead>
        <tr><th>name</th><th>date</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>row1</td><td sorttable_customkey="20041200">Dec 2004</td></tr>
        <tr><td>row2</td><td sorttable_customkey="20100100">Jan 2010</td></tr>
        <tr><td>row3</td><td sorttable_customkey="20110200">Feb 2011</td></tr>
        <tr><td>row4</td><td sorttable_customkey="20100200">Feb 2010</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have an example I can look at? the month there is in number, not month name in English

Answer (score 0):

Using [sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) here. Take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/6mT3QxKcMZEimmxl3Cpx?p=preview. Should be pretty straight forward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <table class="sortable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="">Name</th>
        <th class="">Salary</th>
        <th class="">Extension</th>
        <th class=" sorttable_sorted">Start date<span id="sorttable_sortfwdind">&nbsp;▾</span></th>
      <th class="">Start date (American)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Shakespeare, Bill</td>
          <td>$122000.00</td>
          <td>3211</td>
          <td>12/11/1961</td>
          <td>11/12/1961</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Turvey, Kevin</td>
          <td>$191200.00</td>
          <td>2342</td>
          <td>02/05/1979</td>
          <td>05/02/1979</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fitz, Marvin</td>
          <td>$3300</td>
          <td>5554</td>
          <td>22/05/1995</td>
          <td>05/22/1995</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mbogo, Arnold</td>
          <td>$32010.12</td>
          <td>2755</td>
          <td>09/08/1998</td>
          <td>08/09/1998</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shakespeare, Hamnet</td>
          <td>$9000</td>
          <td>9005</td>
          <td>01/01/2002</td>
          <td>01/01/2002</td>
          </tr><tr><td>Bloggs, Fred</td>
          <td>$12000.00</td>
          <td>1353</td>
          <td>18/08/2003</td>
          <td>08/18/2003</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```